# How add "age" to sort column by clicking on column header?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an add row "age" with sorting data in a table by clicking on column name. I tried many solutions for this, but nothing works. I need the new column "age":
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,CURDATE(),geburtstag) from members

```
<?php
// first creating database connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$database = "celebrates"; //this will contain name of a database
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$action = '';
$sql = "SELECT * from members";
$where = '';
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $id = $_GET["id"]; //geting id value which we are passing from table headers
    $action = $_GET["action"]; // geting action value which we are passing from table headers

    //we are checking condition if $action value is ASC then $action will set to DESC otherwise it will remain ASC
    if($action == 'ASC')
    {
        $action='DESC';
    } else {
        $action='ASC';
    }

    if($_GET['id']=='id') {
        $id = "id";
    } elseif($_GET['id']=='name') {
        $id = "name";
    } elseif($_GET['id']=='vorname') {
        $id="vorname";
    } elseif($_GET['id']=='geburtstag') {
        $id="geburtstag";
    } elseif($_GET['id']=='age') {
        $id = "age";
    } elseif($_GET['id']=='ort') {
        $id = "ort";
    }
    $where = " ORDER BY $id $action ";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members " . $where;
}
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><a href="site.php?id=<?php echo 'name';?>&action=<?php echo $action;?>">NAME</a></th>
    <th><a href="site.php?id=<?php echo 'vorname';?>&action=<?php echo $action;?>">VORNAME</a></th>
    <th><a href="site.php?id=<?php echo 'geburtstag';?>&action=<?php echo $action;?>">GEBURTSTAG</a></th>
    <th><a href="site.php?id=<?php echo 'ort';?>&action=<?php echo $action;?>">ORT</a></th>
    <th><a href="site.php?id=<?php echo 'age';?>&action=<?php echo $action;?>">AGE</a></th>
 </tr>

<?php
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// Fetch a result row as an associative array
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row["name"];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["vorname"];?></td>
   <td><?php echo date("j. F Y", strtotime($row["geburtstag"]));?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['ort'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['age'];?></td>
 </tr>

<?php
    }
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

> **Notice: Undefined index: age in line :** *"php echo $row['age']"*

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: after the while add `print_r($row);` and post the results

Comment: Thanks, but not work.... 
name, vorname, geburtstag, ort are from SQL Table, i want make temporary "age".... How and where?
Thanks

Comment: age is not in table hence the problem

Comment: P.S. as an aside, all the $id if/elseif statements after $id = $_GET["id"]; are effectively redundant. You start by setting the $id var equal to the value of the get request and then you check to see what the value of the get request is and if it is either 'id', 'name' etc., you set the $id var to that value again. It makes no sense.

Comment: I´m new in PHP, Likewise, I do not speak English. I'm German. :)
Can you write me a complete code? 
id = id (primary keys)
name = varchar
vorname = varchar
geburtstag = date
ort = varchar
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not have an column called `age` in your `members` table. Just enhance your query a little bit:

```
$sql = "SELECT members.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,CURDATE(),geburtstag) as age FROM members " . $where
```

Comment: no a have not column "age"

    $where = " ORDER BY $id $action ";
    $sql = "SELECT members.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,geburtstag,CURDATE()) as age FROM members";
    $where = '';

This already shows age, but does not sorting by clicks on the headers

Comment: Thanks :)
Thanks. This is OK :)

`$sql = "SELECT members.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,geburtstag,CURDATE()) as age FROM members" . $where;`

Answer (score 2):

You can't calculate age subtracting years, because the age is calculated also considering days.

Use this query:

```
    SELECT *, 
           YEAR( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) - YEAR( geburtstag ) - (SUBSTR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,6,5 ) < SUBSTR(geburtstag,6, 5)) as age
      FROM members
```

<kbd>**[sqlFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2accd1/1)**</kbd>

By this query, you subtract 1 from years difference if current month/day (`SUBSTR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,6,5)` ) is smaller than birthday month/day (`(SUBSTR(geburtstag,6, 5)`)

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: age in line : "php echo $row['age']"

Thanks, but not work.
Can you help me? Exactly in which rows. I´m new in PHP,
Likewise, I do not speak English. I'm German.

Comment: And then? It will work fine on date. Have you tried and it doesn't work for you?

Comment: I have tried and it works for me. In fact, you can also use `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, but you have to invert args: `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,geburtstag,CURRENT_DATE)`

Comment: Simply replace `$sql = "SELECT * from members";` with above script. Why doesn't works? double chek-it! See also this [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/200293/1) with date type: it works!

Comment: I tried it but it did not work.


`    $where = " ORDER BY $id $action ";`
`    $sql = "SELECT members.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,geburtstag,CURDATE()) as age FROM members";`
`    $where = '';`

This already shows age, but does not sorting by clicks on the headers

Comment: If you write `$where = '';` you will clear previous `$where` content.

Comment: @PeterSchoeller Sorry, If you read my prev comments (now edited) I'm wrong. Now I see that `$action` is `ASC/DESC`, so your syntax `ORDER BY $id $action` is right. I'm very sorry. **If your query still not work,**  place a `echo $sql; die();` before `$result = $conn->query($sql);` and paste output in the comment.

Comment: 192.168.14.9 is a private ip address. It is not accessible worlwide. :)

Comment: Please close this question and open another question asking for this. It's too complicated answering in comment and I can't add another answer because it is off-topic for this question (it has nothing to do with age problem). I'll prepare a detailed answer for another question.

Comment: Thanks. This is OK :)
`$sql = "SELECT members.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,geburtstag,CURDATE()) as age FROM members" . $where;`

Comment: @PeterSchoeller Perfect. Good job.